# What are the dangers associated with removing '.php' from the URL in a procedural PHP application?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I just began building my new site in procedural PHP. I'm going to use the following code on my **.htaccess** file in order to remove **.php** from the URL so that it looks more user friendly. (Eg. site.com/index instead of site.com/index.php, site.com/index?id=5&name=name)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Will I be taking any security risks or possible complexities retrieving values from the URL as head towards further development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It completely safe but I suggest you should done your development first and then change configurations with .htaccess